# Setting the HasDropShadow property on a Popup

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `Popup` control inside of a `ControlTemplate` for a custom `Style`. For this control I would like to set the `HasDropShadow` depending on a variable at the top of the xaml file declared like so:

```
<sys:Boolean x:Key="IsDropShadowEnabled">true</sys:Boolean>
```

So I tried declaring the Popup like so (Only relevant parts shown):

```
<Popup AllowsTransparency=true HasDropShadow="{StaticResource IsDropShadowEnabled}"/>
```

But this gives me the following errors.

> The property "HasDropShadow" does not have an accessible setter.
>
> 'HasDropShadow' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.

So I checked [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.hasdropshadow(v=vs.110).aspx) and sure enough:

> A drop shadow effect displays when the SystemParameters.DropShadow property and the Popup.AllowsTransparency property are set to true.

So instead I thought I could bypass this and set a custom drop shadow on the popup depending on my variable so I tried the following trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="{StaticResource IsDropShadowEnabled}" Value="true">
```

But of course this didn't work with the following error message:

> An object of the type "System.Boolean" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.DependencyProperty".

Is there anyway I can set the drop shadow depending on the static variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by using a `DataTrigger` and binding it to the `StaticResource` like follows:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource IsDropShadowEnabled}}" Value="true">
```

And then providing my own drop shadow using the `DropShadowEffect` class.